# Mail.app on Mac corrupting PDFs

Tags: mail.app

A co-worker is having an issue where PDFs sent as attachments are being corrupted.  If opened through webmail, the attachment is fine.  Any ideas here?

I've rebuilt the Mailbox (using Mail.app's built in feature), but it happened after it.

- Macbook Air
- 2012 Model
- 10.8.3
- Google Apps IMAP
- Happening to PDFs randomly and a powerpoint.

Comment: Could you clarify if you think the corruption is happening during the send (from Mail.app) or the receive (to Mail.app).

Comment: What mail clients are beung used to send and receive the pdfs?

Comment: Mail.app receiving end
Various on sending
PDF won't open and multiple PDF apps say its damaged.  Opening it from Gmail webmail opens it fine.

Comment: fix the corrupt fonts

Comment: Also happening for me, Gmail/Mail.app. Downloading the PDF through webmail and all is fine, opening with Mail.app mostly corrupted. Only happening since Mountain Lion. Also filesizes do not match, Mail.app reporting too small filesizes (hence the corruption).

Comment: Had it happen today with me.  Someone sent me a 15MB Powerpoint (don't ask ;).  Mail.app said it was 15k.  iPhone opened fine.  Is this a Google issue?

Comment: @BradleyChambers Are you looking for advice on how to troubleshoot mail or do you want to edit in some details so that others might be able to know what's happening. You list no steps you took to rebuild the "mailbox", you list no details on what version of Mail, what OS, what specific mail service is delivering the account, etc...

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue at one point.

Try clicking the save button on the top-right corner of the email and designate where to save the files. Then open the file through finder (instead of just clicking on the pdf within the email). This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue. Mail.app seems to convert line breaks in a PDF from Linux to windows style. In a text (PostScript ) block it makes no difference, but it messes up the binary parts of the PDF.